how to apply filter to a button but not the button text using css?
I want to create a button that looks like a stone tablet.
I managed to roughen the borders using a filter. My issue is that this also affects the text on the button.


.stone {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    font-size: 35px;
    background: #ddd; /* Stone-like color */
    border: none; /* Remove default border */
    color: #000; /* Text color */
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150px; /* Center text vertically */
    filter: url(#rough);
}
<button class="stone">foobar</button>

<svg>
  <filter id="rough">
    <feTurbulence x="0" y="0" baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="5" seed="1" />
    <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="7" />
  </filter>
</svg>



Placing an image on the button does not work even when setting a different filter CSS value for the image. Using clip-path is out because polygon crop also cuts the shadow of the button.


img{width:100px;
      height:100px;
    filter:none;}

button {

      width:150px;
      height:150px;
      padding: 10px 5px;
      font-size: 24px;
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0px;
      box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

button:active {

      box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
      transform: translateY(4px);
}

.clip-polygon {
      clip-path: polygon(0% 9%, 88% 10%, 82% 140%, 9% 91%);
}

.thefilter{ 
    filter:url(#wavy2)
}
<button class="clip-polygon">foo bar </button>

<button >foo bar </button>
<button class="thefilter">foo bar </button>

<button class="thefilter"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Greek_uc_sigma.svg/240px-Greek_uc_sigma.svg.png"> </button>

<svg>
  <filter id="wavy2">
    <feTurbulence x="0" y="0" baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="5" seed="1"></feTurbulence>
    <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="5" />
  </filter>
</svg>



While this approach below (based on this answer) achieves getting a filter applied to an image and displaying undistorted text above it, I don't see a way to create a button with this, especially since I don't need/want to use an image.


 .artist_photo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    position:relative;
}

.artist_name{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index:2
}

.artist_photo::after {
    content: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Cat_March_2010-1.jpg/320px-Cat_March_2010-1.jpg');
    display: block;

     filter: url(#rough);
    
    background-size: cover;
   
}

.artist_name {
   color: white;
   background: grey;
}
<div class="artist_photo">
    <div class="artist_name">Some text</div>
</div>

<svg>

  
  <filter id="rough">
    <feTurbulence x="0" y="0" baseFrequency="0.05" numOctaves="5" seed="1" />
    <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="7" />
  </filter>
</svg>



